# Ping Pong rendering using the render of another FBO

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, opengl-3

My goal is to do a Ping Pong rendering using 1 FBO (with 2 color attachments) that use the render of another FBO.

I have an FBO with 5 color buffers.
Then, I want to create a ping pong rendering using for basis 1 of those 5 colors buffers.
So, I create another FBO with 2 buffers colors, then in the for loop, if it's the first iteration, I generate my texture from the other FBO, else I write to the other color buffer.
Last I get out of the FBO and render to the screen.

```
FBOPingPong->bind();

    GLboolean first_iter = true;
    GLboolean ColToUse = 0;
    GLuint amount = 10;

    pingPongShader.Use();
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(pingPongShader.Program, "mod"), ColToUse);
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(pingPongShader.Program, "screenWidth"), (float)w);
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(pingPongShader.Program, "screenHeight"), (float)h);
        if (first_iter) {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FBO->getColorTextures(4)); //It's the texture from the other FBO I want to use
            glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 1);
            glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(pingPongShader.Program, "PingPongTex"), 1);

        }
        else {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FBOPingPong->getColorTextures(ColToUse?0:1));
            glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + ColToUse ? 1 : 0);
            glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(pingPongShader.Program, "PingPongTex"), 1);

        }


        renderQuad(); // render the texture to a quad
        ColToUse = !ColToUse;
        if (first_iter) first_iter = false;
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderQuad();
```

and my fragment shader

## version 330 core

```
//I just want first to make the rendering darker and darker just to know if it works.
in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D PingPongTex;
uniform bool mod;

out vec4 color;

vec3 position() {
    return texture(PingPongTex, TexCoords).xyz;
}

void main()
{
    color = vec4(position(), 1.0f);
}
```

But it seems that `FBO->getColorTextures(4)`  always give me the same result that is not the color buffer I want. It give me the render of normals that is render in `FBO->getColorTextures(1)`.

And I think it only come once in the for loop, because whatever number I give to amount, the result is always the same.

The error is probably stupid, but I am so much in the problem that I can't find it :/

EDIT :
using `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(pingPongShader.Program, "PingPongTex"), 0);` instead of `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(pingPongShader.Program, "PingPongTex"), 1)` made the thing about which color texture to use from the other FBO. This is effectively stupid, since I was trying to write to something that doesn't exist.
But now, after only 1 pass, the screen become black and nothing appear. It's probably a problem of booleans i'm using.

EDIT2 :
Probably something like this would be a better call ...

```
GLboolean first_iter = true;
GLuint amount = 2;

pingPongShader.Use();
for (GLuint i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(pingPongShader.Program, "mod"), i%2);
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(pingPongShader.Program, "screenWidth"), (float)w);
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(pingPongShader.Program, "screenHeight"), (float)h);
    if (first_iter) { // pass 0
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FBO->getColorTextures(4));
        glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 1);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(pingPongShader.Program, "PingPongTex"), 0);
    }
    else {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FBOPingPong->getColorTextures(i%2); // For pass1 I need to read from texture 1
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(pingPongShader.Program, "PingPongTex"), 0);
        glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + ((i+1)%2)); // And I need to write it in texture 0

    }


    renderQuad(); // render the texture to a quad
    if (first_iter) first_iter = false;
```

Comment: "*But it seems that FBO->getColorTextures(4) always give me the same result that is not the color buffer I want.*" OK, but... how am I supposed to know what `getColorTextures(4)` actually does? I don't see an implementation of that function, and it's certainly not an OpenGL API function. It's your function, but you didn't show it. Equally importantly, why are you asking the FBO for information you *already know*? You set that texture into the FBO, so you know what you set there. So just get the texture you actually mean, rather than fetching from the FBO.

Comment: Sorry for the time, I had no acces to internet.
FBO->getColorTextures gives me the GLuint associated with GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT in my FBO.
So call getColorTextures(4) gives me the the texture that is located in the 4th Attachment of my FBO.

My problem here is located in the else statement : when I come to `if (first_iter)` I actually get the texture I want. But when it comes to the else, my render is black. and I don't understand why.

Comment: When you are asking an OpenGL question, you need to show all OpenGL calls and state. If some of this is hidden, we cannot reproduce your work nor examine it for errors.